# add listitem to custom list

Tags: csom, list-item, create-fields

when i try to add listitem to custom list by CSOM there is a problem in getting the name of fields
field name in the list is"Pieces Unaccompanied Hold Baggage(Rush)" ,but when i try to add item ,error fires that the field does not exist

code:

`oListItem.set_item('Pieces Unaccompanied Hold Baggage(Rush)', "value");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got an extra ")" in your code. It should be this way:

```
oListItem.set_item('Pieces Unaccompanied Hold Baggage(Rush)', "value");
```

But, in oListItem.set_item() method, the first parameter shoult be the **INTERNAL** NAME of the field. You will find the internal name in the **URL** when you open the field (column) settings. So it should be

```
oListItem.set_item('InternalName', value)
```

Comment: i removed it but the main error that if field name is more than 2 words it does not work

Comment: You should use the internal name in the set_item function. I have mentioned it in the answer.

Comment: What you are using I suppose is the Display name (name which appears on forms and list views).

Comment: thanks it works but the internal name it only appeared in the URL of the page not on the form

Comment: Yes. A SharePoint field has 3 names - Internal Name (unique name over the site 
 which appears in URL), Display Name (Unique Name within List which appears on forms and list views), static name (somewhat similar to internal). You can read this for a better understanding - https://blogs.perficient.com/2009/04/30/static-name-vs-internal-name-vs-display-name-in-sharepoint/